# In Java How to Input an object defined as Its Interface as argument

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

i have an interface position

```
public interface Position<E>
```

and a class node that implements position

```
protected static class Node<E> implements Position<E>
```

i have a function Traversal that takes Node n as argument

```
public Position<E> Traversal(Node<E> n){...}
```

now i try to pass `Position<String> n` to Traversal as an argument

```
System.out.println(Traversal(n));
```

and get the error

```
 Traversal(Node<E>) is not applicable for the arguments (Position<String>)
```

I can't change

```
Position<E> Traversal(Node<E> n)
```

to

```
Position<E> Traversal(Position<E> n)
```

since I need to use methods in the Node class not defined in the position interface.
So how can I resolve this error?

Comment: I think you either need to re-evaluate your class hierarchy (It's hard for me to tell what is "right" given what you've shared) or you could add another method that can accept a `Position` that does not use methods on `Node`.

Comment: Which JDK are you using? I tried reproducing your issue but things compile fine (JDK 17). Also, is it intentional for `Node<E>` to be static?